# Will the fragments in layout file be loaded automatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/ViewBindingSample)

The layout file activity_main.xml include two fragments both *fragment* and *fragmentBind*.

The project load layout file use MainActivity.kt.

I find that two fragments both *fragment* and *fragmentBind* are loaded automatically, I can't find any code in MainActivity.kt to load the two fragments.

Will the fragments in layout file be loaded automatically in Android Studio?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_activity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.117" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.android.example.viewbindingsample.InflateFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragmentBind"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewActivity" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBind"
        android:name="com.android.example.viewbindingsample.BindFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        binding.textViewActivity.text = getString(string.hello_from_vb_activity)
    }
}
```

**BindFragment.kt**

```
class BindFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_blank) {

    // Scoped to the lifecycle of the fragment's view (between onCreateView and onDestroyView)
    private var fragmentBlankBinding: FragmentBlankBinding? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = FragmentBlankBinding.bind(view)
        fragmentBlankBinding = binding
        binding.textViewFragment.text = getString(string.hello_from_vb_bindfragment)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        // Consider not storing the binding instance in a field, if not needed.
        fragmentBlankBinding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have added Fragments to your xml and it would load when ever setContentView()  in onCreate is called  .

Answer (score 1):

Apart from loading fragments via transaction manually during runtime, a fragment can be added to the layout itself using [fragment tag](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating#AddInLayout)
 as:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The key attribute is `android:name`

```
android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
```

which will inflate and load the fragment in the layout.

As you already know, You can also replace the loaded fragment at runtime using fragment and transaction manager as:

```
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.article_fragment, TabArticleFragment())
transaction.commit()
```

For best practice, use [FragmentContainerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView) instead of `fragment` in XML.